# ESLint unexpected character '@' for JS decorators

Tags: javascript, eslint, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to use decorators in my JS project, however ESLint is throwing an error stating that the @ symbol is a unexpected character.

My code:

```
@observable items = [];
```

My .eslintrc:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 6,
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "jsx": true
            },
            "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "node": true,
            "es6": false
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
            "modules": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "strict": [
            2,
            "global"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            2,
            "single"
        ],
        "indent": [
            2,
            4
        ],
        "eqeqeq": [
            2,
            "smart"
        ],
        "semi": [
            2,
            "always"
        ],
        "max-depth": [
            2,
            4
        ],
        "max-statements": [
            2,
            15
        ],
        "complexity": [
            2,
            5
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no decorators in ES6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want to use [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) which uses Babel to parse things that ESLint hasn't implemented yet (usually experimental features like this). From their README:

> At the moment, you'll need it if you use stuff like class properties, decorators, types.

It is used *with* your current eslint setup, you just have to update some configuration in your `.eslintrc`

Comment: Thanks Matt, I can't make out from that link though if installing babel-eslint should replace my current 'eslint' or do I use it in conjunction with?

Comment: @DeanGibson it's in conjuction. The README has setup instructions. Check out the eslintrc part (`"parser": "babel-eslint",`)

Comment: This quote from babel-eslint's README.md would maybe be more to the point than the eslint issue : "At the moment, you'll need it if you use stuff like class properties, decorators, types."

Comment: How can we fix this for @typescript-eslint/parser

Answer (score 11):

A quick answer:

Install a lib

```
npm i -D babel-eslint
```

Add to your .eslintrc

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you using Visual Code it will not always work. You need to add into User Settings (or Workspace Settings) following parameter:

`{
...
    "eslint.options": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
...
}`

Somehow this option wins anything you put into .eslintrc .

Answer (score 1):

If you using `@babel/core`, you need to install `@babel/eslint-parser`.

Add to your `.eslintrc`

`parser: "@babel/eslint-parser"`

Answer (score -1):

Using `babel-parser` might have fixed the '@'s but caused a bunch of other warnings and errors. What I did was put all the files that used the decorator into a store folder, create an `.eslintignore` file and pointed to that directory.

Answer (score -2):

To fix this you need to choose google as your style guide as follow:

```
    extends: ["google"],
```