# ESlint - @connect react-redux unexpected character

Tags: plugins, npm, syntax-error, react-redux, eslint

I have a problem with configuring ESlint: 
I have this code:

```
@connect((store) => { 
return {
    user: store.user.user,
    userFetched: store.user.fetched,
    tweets: store.tweets.tweets,
  };
})
```

and I can't find a way to configure ESlint, so it does not throw an 'Unexpected token' for the '@connect'.

This is my '.eslintrc.json':

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true
},
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
        "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "react"
],
"rules": {
    "indent": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        0,
        "unix"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        1,
        "double"
    ],
    "semi": [
        2,
        "always"
    ]
}
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem? 
I am most certain that there is a plugin for that but I can't find one.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use babel-eslint for the parser. https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678196/eslint-unexpected-character-for-js-decorators