# Typescript module not found (Vue) and unexpected token @Component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslintrc

**GOAL**
I am trying to setup Typescript, Vue, and Vuetify in Codesandbox, but it seems like nothing will cooperate.

I copied code straight from a normal Vue app initialized with Vue CLI and it doesn't work :/

**PROBLEM**

Typescript will not recognize .vue files (such as `import App from "@/App.vue";` in `main.ts`)

In `App.vue`, eslint keeps flagging @ from the `@Component` decorator EVEN though I set a parser in `.eslintrc.js`

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS**

I tried to solve the problem with Typescript not recognizing .vue files using [Importing Vue components in TypeScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002394/importing-vue-components-in-typescript-file)
BUT it doesn't work anymore. Also, this implementation makes every import hyperlink go to `vue-shim.d.ts`. When I CNTRL click the import to go to the imported file's contents, I go to `vue-shim.d.ts` instead of to the imported file.

I tried solving the `@Component` decorator problem with eslint using [ESLint unexpected character '@' for JS decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678196/eslint-unexpected-character-for-js-decorators)
BUT it did nothing.

**CODE**

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-framework-pjbx1?file=/src/App.vue